# Is it possible to "join" a DownloadStringAsync operation?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code:

```
public static String Download(string address) {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    // Specify a progress notification handler.
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (_sender, _e) => {
        // 
    };

    // ToDo: DownloadStringCompleted event

    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

Instead of having the rest of my code execute in the `DownloadStringCompleted` event handler when the download is complete, can I somehow `Join` this Async request? It will be housed in another thread (doing it this way so I have access to the download progress). I know that `DownloadStringAsync` can take a second parameter; an object called `userToken` in the manual. Could this be of use? Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [manual reset event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent _manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (_sender, _e) =>
        {
            //
        };

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (_sender, _e) => 
        {
            if (_e.Error == null)
            {
                // do something with the results
                Console.WriteLine(_e.Result);
            }
            // signal the event
            _manualReset.Set();
        };

        // start the asynchronous operation
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

        // block the main thread until the event is signaled
        // or until 30 seconds have passed and then unblock
        if (!_manualReset.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
        {
            // timed out ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your revision is even more perfect because I wanted the request to time out after a certain amount of time. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to use [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200.aspx), the synchronous version of `DownloadStringAsync`.  However, it seems that you must use an async method to get the progress notification.  Okay, that's no big deal.  Just subscribe to [DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted.aspx) and use a simple wait handle like [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx) to block until it completes.

One note, I am not sure if the progress notification is even raised for `DownloadStringAsync`.  According to MSDN, [DownloadProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx) is associated with some of the async methods, but not `DownloadStringAsync`.

Comment: "...doing it this way so I have access to the download progress..."

Comment: @SimpleCoder: yeah, I realized my naive answer was wrong after I posted... fixed now, I hope!

Comment: No problem, thanks for the answer! I just tried out Darin Dimitrov's code and the event is indeed raised.